# library not found for -lRCTOrientation

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I'm very beginner in React Native, I build a mobile application which is working OK an android, but when I tried to generate the IPA for iOS using Xcode, I faced this issue

```
ld: library not found for -lRCTOrientation
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

RCTOrientation is shown in red color and i can't find this package in my project folder

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

**1)**

- in Xcode make sure you have followed these 3 steps:

a) Add `node_modules/react-native-orientation/iOS/RCTOrientation.xcodeproj` to your xcode project, usually under the Libraries group

[image]

It should show up somewhere in a list like this:

b) add `libRCTOrientation.a` (from Products under RCTOrientation.xcodeproj) to build target's Linked Frameworks and Libraries list

It should show somewhere in a list like this:

[image]

c) Add `$(SRCROOT)/../node_modules/react-native-orientation/iOS/RCTOrientation/` to Project Name -> Build Settings -> Header Search Paths

Make sure that path is correct, in my case I had to add `/../` inside it, as above for my RN project, the rn-orientation docs specify that without `/../`.

- in Xcode go to Product menu and run Clean build folder
- run `react-native run-ios`

If it still doesn't work try

**2)** Xcode go to Product menu, Schemes, Edit schemes, Build and make sure parallelized build is NOT enabled in Build Options
[image]

If it still doesn't work:

**3)** try to clean all the caches and restart npm:

`rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-* && rm -rf $TMPDIR/haste-* && watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf ios/build && rm -rf node_modules && yarn install && npm start -- --reset-cache`

If you don't have yarn installed just replace `yarn` word with `npm` in the above command.

Source for Xcode add library steps: https://github.com/yamill/react-native-orientation

**UPDATE:** RN 0.60+ supports autolinking and after installing the library with yarn or npm, running a pod install in ios folder, a cache clean, a JS server restart and a rebuild should fix such issues.

Comment: Thank you @florin-dobre i have checked Librairies in Xcode and I noticed that RCTOrientation doesn't exist (it was in red color) and the package wasn't installed in project folder. So I installed it as you told me in your last comment by using
    npm install react-native-orientation --save